# Easiest way to implement cycle crossover

Tags: python

I want to implement cycle crossover in python, and I want to do this in the easiest way. In cycle crossover, a vertex should be copied into the child from one parent, but its position should be inherited from the other parent. 
Here is a link to how it works: 
http://www.rubicite.com/Tutorials/GeneticAlgorithms/CrossoverOperators/CycleCrossoverOperator.aspx

#### Description

> Cycle crossover is an operator in genetic algorithm, to create
>   offsprings for the new population. This crossover is used for problems
>   such as the travel salesman problem, to find the shortest possible
>   route, over generations.

#### Algorithm

> **Cycle Crossover Operator**   The Cycle Crossover operator identifies a number of so-called cycles between two parent chromosomes. Then, to
>   form Child 1, cycle one is copied from parent 1, cycle 2 from parent
>   2, cycle 3 from parent 1, and so on.
>
> Here's an example:
>
> - Parent 1: `8 4 7 3 6 2 5 1 9 0`
> - Parent 2: `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`
>
> **Cycle 1**
>   *Values*: `8 9 0`  which will be marked Orange.
>   We start with the first value in Parent 1 and drop down to the same position in Parent 2. `8` Goes to `0`. Then, we look for
>   `0` in Parent 1 and find it at the 10th position where we drop down to
>   `9`. Again, we look for this value in Parent 1 and find it in the 9th
>   position and drop down to `8`. Since we started with `8`, we've
>   completed our cycle.
>
> - Parent 1: `8 4 7 3 6 2 5 1 9 0`
> - Parent 2: `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`
>
> **Cycle 2**
>   *Values*: 4 1 7 2 5 6 which will be marked Red. 
>   We start with `4` and drop down to `1`. `1` is found in the 8th position in Parent 1 and we drop down to `7`. `7` Drops down
>   to `2`, `2` Drops down to `5`, `5` drops down to `6`, and `6` drops
>   down to `4` - Our cycle is complete.
>
> - Parent 1: `8 4 7 3 6 2 5 1 9 0`
> - Parent 2: `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`
>
> **Cycle 3**
>   *Value*: 3
>   The only possible cycle left is of length 1 and contains the value `3`.
>
> Filling in the offspring:
>
> - Parent 1: `8 4 7 3 6 2 5 1 9 0`
> - Parent 2: `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`
> - Child 1:  `8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 0`
> - Child 2:  `0 4 7 3 6 2 5 1 8 9`
>
> Finishing steps:
>
> - Copy Cycle 1: Cycle 1 values from Parent 1 and copied to Child 1, and
>     values from Parent 2 will be copied to Child 2. Cycle 2 will by
>     different.
> - Copy Cycle 2: Cycle 2 values from Parent 1 will be copied to Child 2,
>     and values from Parent 1 will be copied to Child 1.
> - Copy Cycle 3: Cycle 3 is like Cycle 1, Parent 1 goes to Child 1,
>     Parent 2 goes to Child 2.

I am wondering that is there an easier way to do this.
Thank you

````py
import numpy as np
from copy import deepcopy

class chromosome():
    def __init__(self, genes, id=None, fitness=-1, flatten= False, lengths=None):
        self.id = id
        self.genes = genes
        self.fitness = fitness   

    def describe(self):
        print('ID=#{}, fitenss={}, \ngenes=\n{}'.format(self.id, self.fitness, self.genes))        

    # gives the length of a chromosome
    def chrom_length(self):
        return len(self.genes)

"Cycle crossover" 
def CX(pop, pop_size, selection_method, pc):
    p1 = chromosome(genes= np.array([8,4,7,3,6,2,5,1,9,0]),id=0,fitness = 125.2)  
    p2 = chromosome(genes= np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]),id=1,fitness = 125.2)     
    chrom_length = chromosome.chrom_length(p1)
    print("\nParents")
    print("=================================================")
    chromosome.describe(p1)
    chromosome.describe(p2)
    c1 = chromosome(genes= np.array([-1]*chrom_length),id=0,fitness = 125.2)  # childs
    c2 = chromosome(genes= np.array([-1]*chrom_length),id=1,fitness = 125.2)

    if np.random.random() < pc:  # if pc is greater than random number
        p1_copy = p1.genes.tolist()
        p2_copy = p2.genes.tolist()
        swap = True
        count = 0
        pos = 0   

        while True:
            if count>chrom_length: break
            for i in range(chrom_length):
                if c1.genes[i]==-1:
                    pos=i
                    break

            if swap==True:
                while True:
                    c1.genes[pos] = p1.genes[pos]
                    count+=1
                    pos = p2.genes.tolist().index(p1.genes[pos])
                    if p1_copy[pos] == -1:
                        swap = False
                        break
                    p1_copy[pos] = -1
            elif swap==False:
                while True:
                    c1.genes[pos] = p2.genes[pos]
                    count+=1
                    pos = p1.genes.tolist().index(p2.genes[pos])
                    if p2_copy[pos] == -1:
                        swap = True
                        break
                    p2_copy[pos] = -1

        for i in range(chrom_length): #for the second child
            if c1.genes[i]==p1.genes[i]:
                c2.genes[i]=p2.genes[i]
            else:
                c2.genes[i]=p1.genes[i]

        for i in range(chrom_length): #Special mode
            if c1.genes[i]==-1:
                if p1_copy[i]==-1: #it means that the ith gene from p1 has been already transfered 
                    c1.genes[i]=p2.genes[i]
                else:
                    c1.genes[i]=p1.genes[i]                               

    else:  # if pc is less than random number then don't make any change
        c1 = deepcopy(p1)
        c2 = deepcopy(p2)
    return c1, c2

cross = CX(20, 10,"tour",1)
print("\nChilds")
print("=================================================")
for i in range(len(cross)):
    chromosome.describe(cross[i])
```
````

Comment: Hi, I highly suggest that you explain *here* what's the "cycle crossover" because your link might rot and because it's the best way to get reviewers involved in the review (I, for example, pretty much never click on an external link, I'd skip the post instead).

Comment: At the least, the indentation of the code in this question needs to be fixed.

Comment: Cycle crossover is an operator in genetic algorithm, to create offsprings for the new population. This crossover is used for problems such as the travel salesman problem, to find the shortest possible route, over generations.

Comment: Define 'easiest way'.

Comment: Do the chromosomes actually have 10 genes, or is that a simplification for posting the problem?

Comment: The size of the chromosomes can be different according to the problem.  Their values can also be binary, integer, or floating point.                 @RootTwo

Comment: With least lines of codes. @Mast

Answer (score 4):

## Docstrings

You should include a [`docstring`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings) at the beginning of every method, class, and module you write. It allows anyone to view how to use and implement your method, using `your_function_name.__doc__` or `help(your_function_name)`.

## Class Naming

[PEP-8 Compliance](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names) requires that all class names should use the CapWords convention. In your case, since `Chromosome` is one word, it should be capitalized.

## Reserved Keywords

You have an init header like so:

```
def __init__(self, genes, id=None, fitness=-1, flatten= False, lengths=None):
    ...
```

It is suggested ***not*** to use a variable/parameter name `id`, or any other reserved keywords. This can cause collision and other issues in your program. As a quick fix, I renamed it `id_`, but you can rename it to something more meaningful/easier to understand.

## Unused Arguments

You have two method headers like so:

```
def __init__(self, genes, id=None, fitness=-1, flatten= False, lengths=None):
    ...
def CX(pop, pop_size, selection_method, pc):
    ...
```

You only use four (technically three, since `self` is required in class methods) in the `__init__` method, and one in the `CX` method. If you finish writing a program/method, and see that some parameters you take in aren't used, remove them. This can prevent confusion later on when you decide to take another look at your code and try to find the significance of the parameters you don't use.

## Parameter Spacing

When writing default passed/accepting parameters, there should not be a space between the variable, the `=`, and the value. So, `flatten= False` is not okay, but `flatten=False` is okay. You can look at the updated code, as I fixed every occurrence of this.

## Variable/Operator Spacing

On the contrary, when using variables and operators, there *should* be a space. This allows for better readability. This also accounts for lists. Seeing `[8,4,7,3,6,2,5,1,9,0]`, at least to me, is hard to read. Everything is clumped together. But `[8, 4, 7, 3, 6, 2, 5, 1, 9, 0]` is easier to read and comprehend. Everything is spaced out, and the numbers jump out at you more.

## Main Guard

You have this code lying outside your class/methods:

```
cross = CX(20, 10,"tour",1)
print("\nChilds")
print("=================================================")
for i in range(len(cross)):
    chromosome.describe(cross[i])
```

Wrapping this in a `if __name__ == '__main__':` guard is a good idea. Having a main guard clause in a module allows you to both run code in the module directly and also use procedures and classes in the module from other modules. Without the main guard clause, the code to start your script would get run when the module is imported. [[source]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19578335/8968906)

So your new code should look like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    CROSS = cycle_crossover(1)
    print("\nChildren")
    print("=================================================")
    for index, _ in enumerate(CROSS):
        Chromosome.describe(CROSS[index])
```

*Notice how I use `enumerate()` vs `range(len())`. I explain this change later.*

## Boolean Comparison

```
if swap==True:
    ...
elif swap==False:
    ...
```

This is unnecessary. You can use the variable `swap` as the value itself. You can check the value of `swap` itself to see if it's `True` or `False`, instead of comparing it to the boolean, like so:

```
if swap:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

Also, the second `swap==False` check is unnecessary. If it doesn't pass the first check of being `True`, then it has to be `False`. So only an `else` is necessary here.

## String Formatting f""

This one is my opinion. I like to use `f"..."` to format my strings. It allows me to directly implement the variables into the string, without having to call the `format` method on it. I left both versions in the updated code, just comment out the one you don't like.

## Meaningful Method Naming

`CX`. What do you think of when you first see this? To someone reading your code for the first time, they would have no idea what this method is supposed to do. Methods should have meaningful names, so someone can get the general idea about that method by just looking at the name.

## Variable Naming

You have variables like `p1`, `p2`, `c1`, `c2`, etc. My initial thoughts were that `p1` and `p2` were population one and two, since the parameters in the method were `pop` and `pop_size`. It wasn't until I saw the comment that was `c1` and `c2` were *children* that I realized `p1` and `p2` were *parents*. You should provide more meaningful variable names to avoid this confusion. Also, variable names should be `snake_case`.

## enumerate() vs range(len())

Consider using `enumerate` vs `range(len(...))`. I would use `enumerate` as it's more generic - eg it will work on iterables and sequences, and the overhead for just returning a reference to an object isn't that big a deal - while range(len(...)) although (to me) more easily readable as your intent - will break on objects with no support for `len`.

***Updated Code***

```
"""
Module Docstring:
A description of your program goes here
"""

from copy import deepcopy
import numpy as np

class Chromosome():
    """
    Description of class `Chromosome` goes here
    """
    def __init__(self, genes, id_=None, fitness=-1):
        self.id_ = id_
        self.genes = genes
        self.fitness = fitness

    def describe(self):
        """
        Prints the ID, fitness, and genes
        """
        #print('ID=#{}, fitenss={}, \ngenes=\n{}'.format(self.id, self.fitness, self.genes))
        print(f"ID=#{self.id_}, Fitness={self.fitness}, \nGenes=\n{self.genes}")

    def get_chrom_length(self):
        """
        Returns the length of `self.genes`
        """
        return len(self.genes)

def cycle_crossover(pc):
    """
    This function takes two parents, and performs Cycle crossover on them. 
    pc: The probability of crossover (control parameter)
    """
    parent_one = Chromosome(genes=np.array([8, 4, 7, 3, 6, 2, 5, 1, 9, 0]), id_=0, fitness=125.2)
    parent_two = Chromosome(genes=np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), id_=1, fitness=125.2)
    chrom_length = Chromosome.get_chrom_length(parent_one)
    print("\nParents")
    print("=================================================")
    Chromosome.describe(parent_one)
    Chromosome.describe(parent_two)
    child_one = Chromosome(genes=np.array([-1] * chrom_length), id_=0, fitness=125.2)
    child_two = Chromosome(genes=np.array([-1] * chrom_length), id_=1, fitness=125.2)

    if np.random.random() < pc:  # if pc is greater than random number
        p1_copy = parent_one.genes.tolist()
        p2_copy = parent_two.genes.tolist()
        swap = True
        count = 0
        pos = 0

        while True:
            if count > chrom_length:
                break
            for i in range(chrom_length):
                if child_one.genes[i] == -1:
                    pos = i
                    break

            if swap:
                while True:
                    child_one.genes[pos] = parent_one.genes[pos]
                    count += 1
                    pos = parent_two.genes.tolist().index(parent_one.genes[pos])
                    if p1_copy[pos] == -1:
                        swap = False
                        break
                    p1_copy[pos] = -1
            else:
                while True:
                    child_one.genes[pos] = parent_two.genes[pos]
                    count += 1
                    pos = parent_one.genes.tolist().index(parent_two.genes[pos])
                    if p2_copy[pos] == -1:
                        swap = True
                        break
                    p2_copy[pos] = -1

        for i in range(chrom_length): #for the second child
            if child_one.genes[i] == parent_one.genes[i]:
                child_two.genes[i] = parent_two.genes[i]
            else:
                child_two.genes[i] = parent_one.genes[i]

        for i in range(chrom_length): #Special mode
            if child_one.genes[i] == -1:
                if p1_copy[i] == -1: #it means that the ith gene from p1 has been already transfered
                    child_one.genes[i] = parent_two.genes[i]
                else:
                    child_one.genes[i] = parent_one.genes[i]

    else:  # if pc is less than random number then don't make any change
        child_one = deepcopy(parent_one)
        child_two = deepcopy(parent_two)
    return child_one, child_two

if __name__ == '__main__':

    CROSS = cycle_crossover(1)
    print("\nChildren")
    print("=================================================")
    for index, _ in enumerate(CROSS):
        Chromosome.describe(CROSS[index])
```

Answer (score 2):

The main part of CX can be simplified quite a bit.  `cycles[pos]` is the cycle number of that position, or -1 it hasn't been determined yet. `cyclestart` is a generator that returns the next place for a cycle to start.

```
parent1 = [8, 4, 7, 3, 6, 2, 5, 1, 9, 0]
parent2 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

if np.random.random() < pc:  # if pc is greater than random number

    cycles = [-1]*len(parent1)
    cycle_no = 1
    cyclestart = (i for i,v in enumerate(cycles) if v < 0)

    for pos in cyclestart:

        while cycles[pos] < 0:
            cycles[pos] = cycle_no
            pos = parent1.index(parent2[pos])

        cycle_no += 1

    child1 = [parent1[i] if n%2 else parent2[i] for i,n in enumerate(cycles)]
    child2 = [parent2[i] if n%2 else parent1[i] for i,n in enumerate(cycles)]

else:
    ...

print("parent1:", parent1)
print("parent2:", parent2)
print("cycles:", cycles)
print("child1:", child1)
print("child2:", child2)
```

Prints:

```
parent1: [8, 4, 7, 3, 6, 2, 5, 1, 9, 0]
parent2: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
cycles: [1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]
child1: [8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 0]
child2: [0, 4, 7, 3, 6, 2, 5, 1, 8, 9]
```

If the chromosomes are really long, it might be worth building a dict as a lookup table instead of using `parent1.index()`.  Also changed it so cycle_no comes from enumerating cyclestart (the enumeration starts at 1, so child1 and child2 aren't swapped from the previous answer).

```
lookup = {v:i for i,v in enumerate(parent1)}

cycles = [-1]*len(parent1)
cyclestart = (i for i,v in enumerate(cycles) if v < 0)

for cycle_no, pos in enumerate(cyclestart, 1):

    while cycles[pos] < 0:
        cycles[pos] = cycle_no
        pos = lookup[parent2[pos]]
```